# Monitor filesystem activity of a child process on OS X with normal user privileges

Tags: macos, filesystemwatcher

I spawn a child process and need to know what files it modifies, creates or deletes.

I can't use dtrace because I cannot sudo.

I can't use FSEvents because it reports modifications that occur for all processes on the system and I'm only interested in my child process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would explore using `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` (the Mac OS equivalent of `LD_PRELOAD`) to interpose your own monitoring routine for the libc routines or system calls you are interested in.  For example, you could write a `my_open()` routine that does whatever tracing you are interested in, and then invokes the real libc `open()` to do the rest of the work.  You'll need to do this for all of the filesystem-related calls that you want to trap (open, close, read, write, rename, etc.)  You should be able to set up the `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` environment variable before you spawn your child process, without needing to be root.

There is more information about this, and an example, in Chapter 2 of "Mac OS X Internals: A Systems Approach" by Amit Singh.  If you don't have a copy, you can read the relevant section on [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=K8vUkpOXhN4C&lpg=PA73&ots=OJmmVTRpXx&dq=dyld%20interposing&pg=PA73#v=onepage&q=dyld%20interposing&f=false).